# Suffix Tree and B-Tree

Tags: data-structures, b-tree, suffix-tree

Just a quick question:

**Is a suffix tree (a tree that stores suffixes of words) a type of b-tree please?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the two are not really the same. *Some* B trees are *vaguely* similar to a suffix tree in storing only enough of a key for uniqueness. Other than that, however, there's almost no resemblance between the two at all. In particular, a B tree is defined largely in terms of balancing the tree, which isn't normally used with a suffix tree at all.